# Laravel showing {"message":"Unauthenticated."} when accessing api routes

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Vue + Laravel application. Here I am using laravel API routes to get the data. For the API auth I am using JWT from this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-jwt-authentication-laravel-9/

Now I am getting:

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

error message whne I access to this API route: http://localhost:3000/api/countries

**Country.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'countries';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_country';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'country_name' ,
        'code'         ,
    ];

}
```

**CountryController.php (Controller)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Country;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CountryController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
    
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function countries()
    {
        $country = Country::get();
        return response()->json($country, 200);
    }

}
```

**api.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CountryController;

Route::controller(CountryController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('countries', 'countries')->name("countries");
});
```

Can you tell me what is wrong here and how can I solve it?

Comment: did you include the token given when you sign in on your api call?

Comment: @Doggo No, I see that I have passed the token when login.

Comment: you must copy the token and put it in your header like `bearer [your token here]` or you can directly put it in `auth -> bearer token`

Comment: @Shibbir when you register a user one token is generated and you can use it for login (as your authentication token ) . did you pass that token while in your API call?

Comment: @RachnaGajjar How can I pass the token when calling API?

Comment: @RachnaGajjar I think I passed it to the Ajax call: https://codeshare.io/YLxNMn

Comment: @Doggo Can you check this please: https://codeshare.io/YLxNMn. I have passed the bearer with token.

Comment: the code looks good do you still have any errors?

Comment: @Doggo Yes, I got that error. I should get this only when I log out and try to access that URL.

Comment: you should log the `Cookies.get("jwt-token")`. Check if it had any token may you didn't save the token on the cookie

Comment: maybe you should user `postman` or `insomnia` first before you code your request

Comment: @Doggo `alert(Cookies.get("jwt-token"));` is showing me `undefined`!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248747/discussion-between-doggo-and-shibbir).